# What weapons punch through what cover?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've noticed that some attacks have the capability to punch through cover depending on a combination of the type of cover, the weapon used, and what weapon mods are equipped.

That is, if a enemy "E" is hiding behind cover "C" and I shoot at him with my "M"-modded "W" weapon, enemy "W" may or may not be damaged. **Is there a chart or explanation as to what combination of Cover types, Mods, and Weapons actually allow for successful attacks against an Enemy?**

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between any types of cover and whether they can be shot through, is how thick it is.

Mods and armor piercing ammo are fairly explicit in how thick the cover can be before you will no longer penetrate it.

Apart from that, the only weapons that have an innate ability to penetrate cover are the two Widow Sniper Rifles and the Javelin Sniper Rifle, which can penetrate all thicknesses of cover.

Comment: What constitutes "cover", though? Mods indicate penetrating cover in fractions of a meter -- the lowest value I can find is .25m meters (shotgun), and the highest is 1.35m (sniper rifle). Even a quarter of a meter is an awful lot. More than a meter of cover is essentially a wall.